# Can Mockito verify an argument has certain properties/fields?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

Say I am mocking this class `Foo`

```
class Foo {
  public void doThing(Bar bar) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

and this is `Bar`

```
class Bar {
  private int i;
  public int getI() { return i; }
  public void setI(int i) { this.i = i; }
}
```

I know I can use Mockito's verify functionality to see if `Foo#doThing(Bar)` was called on the mock with a specific instance of `Bar` or any  `Bar` with `Mockito.any(Bar.class)`, **but is there some way to ensure it was called by any `Bar` but with a specific value for `i` or `Bar#getI()`?**

What I know is possible:

```
Foo mockedFoo = mock(Foo.class);
Bar someBar = mock(Bar.class);
...
verify(mockedFoo).doThing(someBar);
verify(mockedFoo).doThing(any(Bar.class);
```

What I want to know is if there is a way to verify that a `Bar` with particular things true about it was passed as an argument.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

In **Mockito 2.1.0 and up with Java 8 you can pass the lambda to argThat out of the box** so that one does not need a custom argument matchers. For the example in the OP would be:

```
verify(mockedFoo).doThing(argThat((Bar aBar) -> aBar.getI() == 5));
```

This is because as of Mockito 2.1.0, `ArgumentMatcher` is a functional interface.

Comment: I can't understand why in my case the lambda is not aware of the type of `aBar`

Comment: @MarioTrucco It's difficult to tell with such little information, are you using Java 8 and Mockito 2.1.0 or above? It's maybe best to post a new question where you describe more in details your problem!

Comment: @MarioTrucco The explicit syntax is `(Bar aBar) -> aBar.getI() == 5`. Maybe typing it out like this will help your IDE figure it out?

Comment: @CaptainMan Yes, that's what I had to write. I will try and confirm whether it is just the IDE's fault

Comment: Fyi, I was able to omit the type name in Intellij and use typical lambda syntax in Java 8 with Mockito 2.7.6, so it could just be an IDE issue.

Comment: Failing this test results in very unreadable error message. Especially when you have multiple calls to the whole `mockedFoo` mock object. So I prefer the @youranos https://stackoverflow.com/a/49687994/1310733 answer. Having `ArgumentCaptor` with many explicit `assertEquals` is much more transparent.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using Mockito 2.1.0 or above and Java 8 or above, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46708152/1858327) answer instead, it's much simpler now.

---

I found the answer while writing the question.

Yes, you can. Instead of using `any(Bar.class)` you'll need to implement your own instance of [`ArgumentMatcher<T>`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.6.1/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html) and use [`Mockito#argThat(Matcher)`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.6.1/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#argThat(org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher)), for example, say we want to check that `i` is 5...

```
// in the test (could also be outside)

private static final class BarIs5 extends ArgumentMatcher<Bar> {
  
  @Override
  public boolean matches(Object argument) {
    return ((Bar) argument).getI() == 5;
  }
}
```

Then verify like so: `verify(mockedFoo).doThing(argThat(new BarIs5()));`

---

Kick it up a notch by adding constructor parameters!

```
private static final class BarIsWhat extends ArgumentMatcher<Bar> {
  
  private final int i;

  public BarIsWhat(int i) {
    this.i = i
  }

  @Override
  public boolean matches(Object argument) {
    return ((Bar) argument).getI() == i;
  }
}
```

Then verify like so: `verify(mockedFoo).doThing(argThat(new BarIsWhat(5)));`

---

**Update:** This popped in my queue because of a badge and saw some room for improvement.

I have tried this and it works. You can sort of use a lambda expression which is a lot cleaner (if you don't mind unchecked cast warnings at least).

The only issue is that `argThat` accepts a Hamcrest `Matcher` which is *not* a `@FunctionalInterface`. Luckily, Mockito's `ArgumentMatcher` is an abstract class that extends it and only has a single abstract method.

In your test (or some common location) make a method like below

```
private static <T> ArgumentMatcher<T> matches(Predicate<T> predicate) {
  return new ArgumentMatcher<T>() {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object argument) {
      return predicate.test((T) argument);
    }
  };
}
```

Now, in your test you can do this to use a lambda expression:

```
verify(mockedFoo).doThing(argThat(matches( (Bar arg) -> arg.getI() == 5 )));
```

Answer (score 13):

If using Mockito 2+ is not an option, you can also use good old `ArgumentCaptor`. It'll be a bit more verbose though:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Long> siteIdCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Long.class);
verify(repository).findBySiteId(siteIdCaptor.capture());
assertEquals(15, siteIdCaptor.getValue().longValue());
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you are looking for the `when.. then..` syntax, this should be a working alternative:

```
doReturn(valueToReturn).when(mockedFoo).doThing(argThat((Bar aBar) -> aBar.getI() == 5));
```

Comment: yes I was looking for this syntax, thanks

Comment: Note that stubbing with argument captor is not recommended. The OP wants to **verify** the argument attributes and not to do specific mock for given argument. Two different things :)
See https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argumentcaptor

Answer (score 0):

with Kotlin and mockito-kotlin library this can be tricky. You need to create an extension function on class `Bar`. I'd like to share an example:

```
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.argThat
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.mock
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.verify
// ...

    @Test
    fun testBar() {
        val mockedFoo: Foo = mock()
        val someBar: Bar = mock()
        // ...
        fun Bar.hasExpectedValue() = this.getI() == 5
        verify(mockedFoo).doThing(argThat( Bar::hasExpectedValue ))
    }
```